# error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token" and "cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I was writing a converter form Italian lires to Euros in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float x;

int converter (x)
{
    y = x/1936,27;
    return y;
}

int main() 
{
    cout << "Give me the value: ";
    cin >> x;
    converter (x);
}
```

I try to compile it and i see two errors. The first one is:

```
lire-euro.cpp:8: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

I defined a function before the parenthesis. Why should I put `','` or `';'` before `'{'`?
The second one is:

```
lire-euro.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
lire-euro.cpp:17: error: ‘converter’ cannot be used as a function
```

Why i can't use `converter` as a function? Is this related to the other error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function parameter list is missing the parameter type:

```
int converter (float x) { ...
//             ^^^^^
```

Besides that, inside the body of the function you use `y`, which is undeclared. You can fix that problem by returning the expression, but you may have to replace the `,` in your floating point literal by a `.`, depending on your locale.

```
return x/1936.27;
```

Note that it may make more sense to return a floating point number rather than an `int`.

Finally, I see no reason for `x` to be global. You could declare it inside of `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>

int converter(float x)
{
    return x/1936.27;
}

int main() 
{
    float x;
    std::cout << "Give me the value: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    int z = converter(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in the function definition. First of all its parameter x has no type specifier and its local variable y also was not defined.

I think you meant

```
float x;

int converter()
{
    int y = x/1936,27;
    return y;
}
```

Though I am not sure whether y (and the function return type) should be defined as int.

The corresponding call of the functioo could look as

```
cout << converter() << endl;
```

Comment: And third, although not an error, the `converter` can be rewritten into `x/1936; int y = 27;` for clarity. :)